# Custom link handling (no following) in JS

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

Using `JavaScript`, I just did this. When a link is clicked, beside following the link, it also copies the associated text to the clipboard, if the mouse button is kept down more than 2 seconds.

This is the HTML:

```
<a onmousedown='startChrono();' onmouseup='checkChrono(this.id);'
               id='SomeID' href='http://SomeUrl.org' %>'>Some meaningful text</a>
```

And these are the two functions, where *referDate* is defined globally:

```
function startChrono() {
    referDate = new Date().getTime();
}


function checkChrono(objId) {
    let currentDate = new Date().getTime();

    if ((currentDate - referDate) > 2000) {
        copyStr(objId);
    }
}
```

The code for *copyStr()* being irrelevant for the question, I do not include it.

Here is where I need some help.
**What should I change in the code above, to prevent the link from following through in the case the button has been kept down more than 2 seconds?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let referDate;

function copyStr(obj){
    console.log(`2+ sec, str of "${obj.id}" with content "${obj.innerHTML}" copied! ( actually not :P )`)
}
function startChrono() {
    referDate = new Date().getTime();
}

function checkChrono(obj,ev) {/*no need for id, we can use object itself!*/
  let currentDate = new Date().getTime()
  
  if ((currentDate - referDate) > 2000) {
    ev.preventDefault()
    copyStr(obj)
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="a-id" onmousedown="startChrono();" onclick="checkChrono(this,event);" href="/"> click </a>
```

Comment: Interesting, but why do you comment out copyStr(objId)? I need that to copy the text to the clipboard.

Comment: just because I don't have that function :P

Comment: Ah :) OK (Sorry). So if I put it back it should, work. But I just tried and it keeps following the link, I must have missed something.

Comment: you need to keep 2 sec and more, it's a bit longer than my thought. And answer updated to show some more things.

Comment: I kept about 3 seconds. And made several trials.

Comment: I see. I need to try more. At this point, I keep following the link.

Comment: I just noticed you use onclik and not onmouseup. That may be why? But the events are different ..... I need to test.

Comment: yes, you need to prevent default inside `onclick`, not `onmouseup`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) being called by onclick instead of mousedown.

```js
var referDate;
function startChrono() {
  referDate = new Date().getTime();
}

function checkChrono(event, objId) {
   
  let currentDate = new Date().getTime();

  if ((currentDate - referDate) > 2000) {
    event.preventDefault(); // cancels the click event
    //copyStr(objId);
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Text Copied";
  } 
  else{
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Follows the link";
  }
  
}
```

```html
<a onmousedown='startChrono();' 
   onclick='checkChrono(event, this.id);' 
   id='SomeID' target="_blank" 
   href='https://google.com'>Some meaningful text</a>

<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion it almost works, but I want to keep the copying to the clipboard.

Comment: Yes, I commented out the copyStr(obj) function to make it work here, since I didn't have the copyStr function details. You can continue using the copyStr(objId) function, instead of populating the "text" div. :)

Comment: OK. But in my case I still follows the link, I don't know why.

Comment: It works for me on CodePen also: https://codepen.io/akshatamohanty/pen/PReMMp. Maybe decrease the time duration from 2000 to 300 ms and try? To me it seemed like quite a long mouse press!

Comment: There was also another interesting solution, which was unfortunately removed. Based on the use of onmouseup, without using .preventDefault(). onclick only returning false. I only had time to see and test it, not to upvote it :(